# Create a list that follows a certain creation pattern

Tags: python, list

What is an easy way to create a list following a certain pattern, e.g. start with x, add 1, add 3, add 1, add 3, ...

I came up with this method, but there is certainly a better (more compact) way:

```
i = 0
n = 100
l = []
for x in range(int(n/2)):
    i = i + 1
    l.append(i)
    i = i + 3
    l.append(i)
```

which creates the list

```
[1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 16, 17, 20, 21, 24, 25, 28, 29, 32, 33, 36, 37, 40, 41, 44, 45, 48, 49, 52, 53, 56, 57, 60, 61, 64, 65, 68, 69, 72, 73, 76, 77, 80, 81, 84, 85, 88, 89, 92, 93, 96, 97, 100, 101, 104, 105, 108, 109, 112, 113, 116, 117, 120, 121, 124, 125, 128, 129, 132, 133, 136, 137, 140, 141, 144, 145, 148, 149, 152, 153, 156, 157, 160, 161, 164, 165, 168, 169, 172, 173, 176, 177, 180, 181, 184, 185, 188, 189, 192, 193, 196, 197, 200]
```

What about more complex patterns, like +1, -2, +3, +1, -2, +3, ...

Comment: Your code throws a `TypeError` at the moment. What is the desired output in your example?

Comment: sorry, there where a few (dumb) syntax errors. i fixed them now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python provides a [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) function in itertools that is helpful with this:

```
from itertools import cycle

i = 0
n = 10
l = []
step = cycle([1, -2, 3])

for _ in range(n):
    i += next(step)
    l.append(i)

print(l)
```

Giving you:

```
[1, -1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7]
```

Or alternatively you could do the following one liner:

```
from itertools import accumulate, islice, cycle
import operator

l = list(accumulate(islice(cycle([1, -2, 3]), 10), operator.add))
print(l)
```

[`accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) was added in version 3.2

Comment: @JonClements no you can use this one here, to give it an arbitrary starting number: `l = list(accumulate([10] + list(islice(cycle([1, -2, 3]), 9)), operator.add))` idk, maybe not the most elegant way but it works

Comment: @reox oh - it can be worked around in various ways - I was just pointing out that  the accumulate solution as suggested works by coincidence that `i == 0` works, but it's not identical to the for loop using cycle where `i != 0`

Comment: @reox here's a version that keeps it lazy and doesn't required builiding a list for `accumulate` -- `list(islice(accumulate(repeat(i, n + 1), lambda a, _, b=cycle([1, -2, 3]): a + next(b)), 1, None))`

Answer (score 0):

```
# Function
# Can accept an existing list to be added to (_result_list) which is optional
# If _result_list is not included it is created from scratch

def AddList(_factors_list, _result_list = [] ):
    # Loop through the _factors_list (values to be added)
    for _value in  _factors_list:
        # If _result_list (either passed in or created by function) contains
        # no values, add the first item from _factors_list as the first entry
        if len( _result_list ) < 1: 
            _result_list.append( _value )
            continue # Go to the next item in the _factors_list loop
        # If _result_list already has values
        else: 
            # _result_list[len(_result_list) - 1] takes the last item in list
            # Don't use 'pop' as that removes the item
            # Append the next item as 'last item' + 'current_loop_value'
            _result_list.append( _result_list[len(_result_list) - 1] + _value )
            continue # Go to the next item in the _factors_list loop
    #Def all done. Return the _result_list
    return _result_list

result_list = [] # Optional, but can be an existing list
factors_list = [1,-2,3, 5, -4] # Items to be added
# test without existing list
result_list = AddList(factors_list)
print result_list

# test WITH existing list
result_list = [9, 8, 3] # Optional, but can be an existing list
factors_list = [1,-2,3, 5, -4] # Items to be added
result_list = AddList(factors_list, result_list)
print result_list
```

EDIT:
You can also use a random function

```
import random
result_list = AddList(random.sample(range(-100, 100), 10))
print result_list
```